# Definition of math_sin function in the CPython source code?

Tags: python, cpython, python-internals

I am studing the codebase of CPython.

I would like to know where can I find the definition of the `math_sin` function that appears in the `mathmethods` table in `mathmodule.c`:

```c
{"sin",             math_sin,       METH_O,         math_sin_doc}
```

Doing `grep "math_sin" -wr` in the main `cpython` folder only returns:

```c
Modules/mathmodule.c:    {"sin",             math_sin,       METH_O,         math_sin_doc},
```

Where can I find the definition of this function?

Comment: @JohnColeman: not entirely. That question covers where the sin implementation is ultimately found (which is to use the POSIX `math.h` `double sin(double x)` function), not where the `math_sin` implementation, which would be responsible for the marshalling between Python's float type and C double, is defined.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I see the distinction. I'll retract my close-vote.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`math_sin` is defined via the [`FUNC1` macro](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/23bace26ec265557697cf3b578b361c178070cd5/Modules/mathmodule.c#L1199-L1201):

```c
FUNC1(sin, sin, 0,
      "sin($module, x, /)\n--\n\n"
      "Return the sine of x (measured in radians).")
```

where [`FUNC1` is defined as](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/23bace26ec265557697cf3b578b361c178070cd5/Modules/mathmodule.c#L1055-L1059):

```c
#define FUNC1(funcname, func, can_overflow, docstring)                  \
    static PyObject * math_##funcname(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) { \
        return math_1(args, func, can_overflow);                            \
    }\
    PyDoc_STRVAR(math_##funcname##_doc, docstring);
```

so the preprocessor expands this to:

```c
    static PyObject * math_sin(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
        return math_1(args, sin, 0);
    }
    PyDoc_STRVAR(math_sin_doc, "sin($module, x, /)\n--\n\n"
      "Return the sine of x (measured in radians).");
```

(but then all on one line, and with the `PyDoc_STRVAR` macro also having been expanded)

So `math_sin(module, args)` basically is a call to `math_1(args, sin, 0)`, and [`math_1(args, sin, 0)`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/mathmodule.c#L1010-L1014) calls [`math_1_to_whatever(args, sin, PyFloat_FromDouble, 0)`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/23bace26ec265557697cf3b578b361c178070cd5/Modules/mathmodule.c#L899-L961) which takes care of validating that a Python float was passed in, converting that to a C double, calling `sin(arg_as_double)`, raising exceptions as needed or wrapping the double return value from `sin()` with the `PyFloat_FromDouble` function passed in by `math_1()` before returning that result to the caller.

`sin()` here is [the `double sin(double x)` function defined in POSIX `math.h`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sin).

You can, in principle, preprocess the whole Python source tree and dump the output into a new directory; the following does presume you successfully built the `python` binary already, as it is used to extract the necessary include flags for `gcc`:

```sh
find . -type d -exec mkdir -p /tmp/processed/{} \;
(export FLAGS=$(./python.exe -m sysconfig | grep PY_CORE_CFLAGS | cut -d\" -f2) && \
 find . -type f \( -name '*.c' -o -name '*.h' \) -exec gcc -E $FLAGS {} -o /tmp/processed/{} \;)
```

and then `math_sin` will show up in `/tmp/preprocessed/Modules/mathmodule.c`.

Or you can tell the compiler to save preprocessor output to `.i` files with the `-save-temps` flag:

```sh
make clean && make CC="gcc -save-temps"
```

and you'll find `make_sin` in `Modules/mathmodule.i`.

Comment: Thanks Pieters, but where does the POSIX math.h definiton of sin comes from? #include <math.h> is not in the mathmodule.c or in _math.c

Comment: @PintoDoido: it's included in [`pyport.h`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7e954e7de4f3777b5ce239640bd2b76aced09561/Include/pyport.h#L212).